# HybirdAuth User profile request failed

Tags: php, cakephp, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I am using HybridAuth2 with CakePHP and my controller function is as

```
public function loginwith($provider) {
        //        $this->autoRender = false;
        require_once( WWW_ROOT . 'hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php' );

        $hybridauth_config = array(
            "base_url" => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->base . "/hybridauth/", // set hybridauth path
            "providers" => array(
                "Google" => array(
                    "enabled" => true,
                    "keys" => array("id" => "clientID", "secret" => "clientSecret")
                )
            )
        );

        try {
            // create an instance for Hybridauth with the configuration file path as parameter
            $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($hybridauth_config);

            // try to authenticate the selected $provider
            $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider);

            // grab the user profile
            $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

            debug($user_profile); 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Display the recived error
            switch ($e->getCode()) {
                case 0 : $error = "Unspecified error.";
                    break;
                case 1 : $error = "Hybriauth configuration error.";
                    break;
                case 2 : $error = "Provider not properly configured.";
                    break;
                case 3 : $error = "Unknown or disabled provider.";
                    break;
                case 4 : $error = "Missing provider application credentials.";
                    break;
                case 5 : $error = "Authentification failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.";
                    break;
                case 6 : $error = "User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected to the provider and he should to authenticate again.";
                    $adapter->logout();
                    break;
                case 7 : $error = "User not connected to the provider.";
                    $adapter->logout();
                    break;
            }

            // well, basically you should not display this to the end user, just give him a hint and move on..
            $error .= "Original error message: " . $e->getMessage();
            $error .= "Trace: " . $e->getTraceAsString();
            $this->set('error', $error);
        }
    }
```

The HybridAuth Library is in the webroot folder under app folder

however, i am getting the error which is in **case 6** i.e.

**case 6 : $error = "User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected to the provider and he should to authenticate again.";**

The exact error message is `Undefined variable: adapter [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 177]` which points to CASE 6

Can anyone suggest what's going on. I am unable to debug this.

**P.S. This happens only with Google Login**

Regards,
Guns

Comment: I know this is fairly old now but I just got this too and have no idea how I created it. I had to go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 and revoke my web app from Google and log back in. I'd really like to know what caused this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is more than half an year old but here you go the solution:

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and activate Google+ API access.

I ran into this problem earlier today and that worked out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No prob. Usually I'm the guy with all the questions and no answers :D